# MySQL C API: Getting `MYSQL_FIELD` array from `MYSQL_STMT`?

Tags: mysql, c

I have prepared and executed a `MYSQL_STMT` and now I want to fetch the data.

I can get the number of fields with `mysql_stmt_field_count`.

I need to know the `MYSQL_FIELD` information for each field.

How do I get the `MYSQL_FIELD` information?

There is a `field` member of type `MYSQL_FIELD*` in `MYSQL_STMT` but in the manual it says:

> The MYSQL_STMT structure has no members intended for application use.

There are several functions that take a `MYSQL_RES` such as `mysql_fetch_fields`, but I do not have a `MYSQL_RES`, I have a `MYSQL_STMT`

Documentation is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using prepared statements, you should exactly know type and size of each field, in order to prepare `MYSQL_BIND` array

Following code snippet was taken from [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-stmt-fetch.html)

```
MYSQL_BIND    bind[4]; // 4 columns
MYSQL_TIME    ts;
unsigned long length[4];
int           param_count, column_count, row_count;
short         small_data;
int           int_data;
char          str_data[STRING_SIZE];
my_bool       is_null[4];
my_bool       error[4];

/* Bind the result buffers for all 4 columns before fetching them */

memset(bind, 0, sizeof(bind));

/* INTEGER COLUMN */
bind[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
bind[0].buffer= (char *)&int_data;
bind[0].is_null= &is_null[0];
bind[0].length= &length[0];
bind[0].error= &error[0];

/* STRING COLUMN */
bind[1].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[1].buffer= (char *)str_data;
bind[1].buffer_length= STRING_SIZE;
bind[1].is_null= &is_null[1];
bind[1].length= &length[1];
bind[1].error= &error[1];

/* SMALLINT COLUMN */
bind[2].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_SHORT;
bind[2].buffer= (char *)&small_data;
bind[2].is_null= &is_null[2];
bind[2].length= &length[2];
bind[2].error= &error[2];

/* TIMESTAMP COLUMN */
bind[3].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP;
bind[3].buffer= (char *)&ts;
bind[3].is_null= &is_null[3];
bind[3].length= &length[3];
bind[3].error= &error[3];
```

Comment: I'm writing a generic wrapper object for prepared statements so each instance will have a different set of fields - so I can't hardcode the MYSQL_BIND array like this.  It is necessary to get information about each field to setup the MYSQL_BIND array correctly.  Since writing the question I have figured out how to do it: First you call prepare, and then mysql_stmt_result_metadata(MYSQL_STMT) to get a special MYSQL_RES that only contains metadata.  The MYSQL_RES can then be used with mysql_fetch_fields (and others) to get information about each field type. (all before execute is called).

Answer (score -1):

> Before binding variables to the MYSQL_BIND structures that are to be
>   used for fetching column values, you can check the type codes for each
>   column of the result set. This might be desirable if you want to
>   determine which variable types would be best to use to avoid type
>   conversions. To get the type codes, call mysql_stmt_result_metadata()
>   after executing the prepared statement with mysql_stmt_execute(). The
>   metadata provides access to the type codes for the result set as
>   described in Section 22.9.7.23, “mysql_stmt_result_metadata()”, and
>   Section 22.9.1, “C API Data Structures”.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-stmt-result-metadata.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.